# Mobile menu doesn't show in Material Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCss and I have a default menu as well as mobile menu, following the example from [their website](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-tabs). When the screens becomes smaller, the top menu row should disappear and the site needs to only show the bars for mobile version menu.

It doesn't work. When I click I see no behavior but also no messages. The linkage between the component and the size is set. Feeling very confused how to troubleshoot.

Have a look at this non-working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/6d7oaL5n/).

```
<a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="right button-collapse">
  <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</a>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="application left hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li><a id="home-menu" href="#">START</a></li>
  <li><a id="uno-menu" href="#">BEEP</a></li>
  <li><a id="duo-menu" href="#">BLOPP</a></li>
  <li><a id="tres-menu" href="#">POPP</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="mobile-demo" class="application side-nav">
  <li><a id="home-mob-menu" href="#vinn">START mob</a></li>
  <li><a id="uno-mob-menu" href="#vinn">BEEP mob</a></li>
  <li><a id="duo-mob-menu" href="#krita">BLOPP mob</a></li>
  <li><a id="donkey-mob-menu" href="#demos">SNOPP mob</a></li>
  <li><a id="monkey-mob-menu" href="#misc">ROPP mob</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the examples described in the mobile section of the docs:

http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html#options

Here's my attempt:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-3">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">SPA</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#main/interesting-section">Interesting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#main/interesting-section">Interesting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and it needs the following javascript to initialise:

```
$(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
})
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/markwill/pen/WoOmLx)

Comment: I copied wrong fiddle. Corrected the JS now but still get the same issue as before. Nothing happens. (Well, the screen goes dark but nothing else than that...) Please take a look. Perhaps I'm still missing something...

Comment: Hi Konrad - I can't see a button-collapse class (which is used to give a hamburger effect), also in the docs (components section) the navbar uses a class such as 'hide-on-med-and-down' to selectively hide based on device size?

Comment: Stupid JsFiddle didn't save the changes. Please try again [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/6d7oaL5n/). And yes, the hiding works. The menu will disappear when the screen becomes narrow. But the menu doesn't pop up when I click the "menu bars"

Comment: Hi, I've replaced your mobile section with mine: https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/6d7oaL5n/8/ - so I'd just look to insert your own menu links into that format. Maybe it's just a case of needing the 'side-nav' class and maybe the id?

Comment: I also noted you have several <ul> elements in your mobile section, where the example has one containing each link in an <li>.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the side nav

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-tabs

To get the hamburger icon effect, you need this

```
<i class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

Comment: JsFiddle didn't save my changes. Please try again [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/6d7oaL5n/). As you will see, I can hide the menu by narrowing the screen and get a shadowing effect when clicking the burger. But I can't get the menu to show...

Comment: The menu needs to be

Comment: The menu need to be like this <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: data-activates and the id of the menu must match